# GPS North? South? East? West?

Tags: gps

I'm using the Adafruit SIM808 breakout board to text a GPS link to Google Maps when pinged. My program is mostly working, but the GPS data that I get has no "N, S, E, W" indicators. In addition, I know that the longitude where I live is negative but it's coming out as positive. This is the output that I get:

[image]

This is the code that triggers that output:

```
int8_t stat;
// check GPS fix
stat = fona.GPSstatus();
if (stat < 0)  {
  Serial.println(F("Failed to query"));
}
if (stat == 0) {
  Serial.println(F("GPS off"));
}
if (stat == 1) {
  Serial.println(F("No fix"));
}
if (stat == 2) {
  Serial.println(F("2D fix"));
}
if (stat == 3) {
  Serial.println(F("3D fix"));
}

// check for GPS location
char gpsdata[120];
fona.getGPS(0, gpsdata, 120);
Serial.println(gpsdata);
```

I'm already reading about how to fix the GPS data so that it can be used by Google Maps, but I don't know what to do about the issue of not having the directional information/sign.

Here is the full code, just for reference:

```
#include "Adafruit_FONA.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define FONA_RX 2
#define FONA_TX 3
#define FONA_RST 4
#define FONA_KEY 7
#define FONA_PS 8

// this is a large buffer for replies
char replybuffer[255];

SoftwareSerial fonaSS = SoftwareSerial(FONA_TX, FONA_RX);
SoftwareSerial *fonaSerial = &fonaSS;
Adafruit_FONA fona = Adafruit_FONA(FONA_RST);
uint8_t readline(char *buff, uint8_t maxbuff, uint16_t timeout = 0);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(FONA_KEY, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FONA_PS, INPUT);
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
  delay(2000);

  TurnOffFona();

  Serial.println(F("FONA SMS caller ID test"));
  Serial.println(F("Initializing....(May take 3 seconds)"));
  delay(1000);

  TurnOnFona();

  fonaSerial->begin(4800);
  if (! fona.begin(*fonaSerial)) {
    Serial.println(F("Couldn't find FONA"));
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println(F("FONA is OK"));

  // Print SIM card IMEI number.
  char imei[15] = {0}; // MUST use a 16 character buffer for IMEI!
  uint8_t imeiLen = fona.getIMEI(imei);
  if (imeiLen > 0) {
    Serial.print("SIM card IMEI: "); Serial.println(imei);
  }

  // turn GPS on
  if (!fona.enableGPS(true)) {
    Serial.println(F("GPS failed to turn on"));
  }

  Serial.println("FONA Ready");
}


char fonaInBuffer[64]; //for notifications from the FONA

void loop() {
  char* bufPtr = fonaInBuffer; //handy buffer pointer

  if (fona.available()) {
    //any data available from the FONA?
    int slot = 0; //this will be the slot number of the SMS
    int charCount = 0;
    //Read the notification into fonaInBuffer
    do  {
      *bufPtr = fona.read();
      Serial.write(*bufPtr);
      delay(1);
    } while ((*bufPtr++ != '\n') && (fona.available()) && (++charCount < (sizeof(fonaInBuffer) - 1)));

    //Add a terminal NULL to the notification string
    *bufPtr = 0;

    //Scan the notification string for an SMS received notification.
    //  If it's an SMS message, we'll get the slot number in 'slot'
    if (1 == sscanf(fonaInBuffer, "+CMTI: \"SM\",%d", &slot)) {
      Serial.print("slot: "); Serial.println(slot);
      char callerIDbuffer[32];  //we'll store the SMS sender number in here

      // Retrieve SMS sender address/phone number.
      if (! fona.getSMSSender(slot, callerIDbuffer, 31)) {
        Serial.println("Didn't find SMS message in slot!");
      }
      Serial.print(F("FROM: ")); Serial.println(callerIDbuffer);

      int8_t stat;
      // check GPS fix
      stat = fona.GPSstatus();
      if (stat < 0)  {
        Serial.println(F("Failed to query"));
      }
      if (stat == 0) {
        Serial.println(F("GPS off"));
      }
      if (stat == 1) {
        Serial.println(F("No fix"));
      }
      if (stat == 2) {
        Serial.println(F("2D fix"));
      }
      if (stat == 3) {
        Serial.println(F("3D fix"));
      }

      // check for GPS location
      char gpsdata[120];
      fona.getGPS(0, gpsdata, 120);
      Serial.println(gpsdata);
      String gpsString;

      gpsString = (String) gpsdata; //re-cast chr array as string.
      Serial.println(gpsString);
      int commaIndex = gpsString.indexOf(',');
      int secondCommaIndex = gpsString.indexOf(',', commaIndex + 1);
      int thirdCommaIndex = gpsString.indexOf(',', secondCommaIndex + 1);
      int fourthCommaIndex = gpsString.indexOf(',', thirdCommaIndex + 1);

      String firstValue = gpsString.substring(0, commaIndex);
      String rawLat = gpsString.substring(commaIndex + 1, secondCommaIndex);
      String rawLon = gpsString.substring(secondCommaIndex + 1, thirdCommaIndex);
      String rawAlt = gpsString.substring(thirdCommaIndex + 1, fourthCommaIndex);

      int decimalIndex = rawLat.indexOf('.');
      String lat1 = rawLat.substring(0, decimalIndex);
      String lat2 = rawLat.substring(decimalIndex + 1, rawLat.length());
      Serial.println(lat1);
      Serial.println(lat2);
      rawLat = lat1.substring(0, 2) + "." + lat1.substring(3, lat1.length()) + lat2;
      Serial.println(rawLat);

      int decimal2Index = rawLon.indexOf('.');
      String lon1 = rawLon.substring(0, decimal2Index);
      String lon2 = rawLon.substring(decimal2Index + 1, rawLon.length());
      Serial.println(lon1);
      Serial.println(lon2);
      rawLon = lon1.substring(0, 2) + "." + lon1.substring(3, lon1.length()) + lon2;
      Serial.println(rawLon);

      char txtmsgArray[80];
      String txmsg = "https://www.google.com/maps/@" + rawLat + "," +  rawLon + ",15z";
      txmsg.toCharArray(txtmsgArray, 80);
      Serial.println(txtmsgArray);

      Serial.println("Sending reponse...");
      if (!fona.sendSMS(callerIDbuffer, txtmsgArray)) {
        Serial.println(F("Failed"));
      } else {
        Serial.println(F("Sent!"));
      }
      delay(3000);
      // delete the original msg after it is processed
      //   otherwise, we will fill up all the slots
      //   and then we won't be able to receive SMS anymore
      if (fona.deleteSMS(slot)) {
        Serial.println(F("OK!"));
      } else {
        Serial.println(F("Couldn't delete"));
      }
    }
  }
}

void TurnOnFona() {
  Serial.println("Turning on Fona: ");
  while (digitalRead(FONA_PS) == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(FONA_KEY, LOW);
  }
  digitalWrite(FONA_KEY, HIGH);
  delay(4000);
}

void TurnOffFona() {
  Serial.println("Turning off Fona ");
  while (digitalRead(FONA_PS) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(FONA_KEY, LOW);
  }
  digitalWrite(FONA_KEY, HIGH);
  delay(4000);
}
```

Comment: Using `AT+CGPSINF=1` should give you NMEA formatted data. That may be of more use to you.

Answer (score 2):

Send the command:
`AT+CGPSOUT=1`

That should enable the output of the standard NMEA $GPGGA string which includes all the position information you should need in a format that either you can parse or use one of the many existing libraries to parse. It's not clear from the documentation if this will be a one time output or a 1 Hz output.

There are other NMEA messages available if you need them, see https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SIM808_GPS_Application_Note_V1.00.pdf for details.

Answer (score 1):

GPS is a positioning system: it doesn't do direction.  If your software has serial information coming in,  it can take the difference in readings and *generate* that data but GPS doesn't do it for you.

Some devices may add it to the standard,  but that's a per-device feature. .

Comment: Op is asking for the hemisphere not the direction

Comment: No he wasn't, that's "in addition"